# grafana - add new column

Tags: sql, monitoring, grafana

i use grafana with table panel, i can put 3 column (metric,value,time) but i want put 5 column (metric, metric, value, value, time)

how can i see 5 column in a table?

see below with 3 column

[image]

i need 5 column

sql in grafana panel :

[image]

that works, i use a new version of table in grafana

Comment: I think the `table` panel handles same name columns. Worth a try anyway. Maybe  `aliasing` column os_name as `metric_1` and program as `metric_2`. Just to be sure this is not a name clash issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same name column more than once. Change the name of the columns and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do that with Grafana tooltip, identical columns name are forbidden by MySQL, nor Grafana. on your query set unique alias for each column.

on your table visualization configuration change the names as you wish.

for example:
`SELECT time as time,  line as value1,  nb_user as value2, os_name as metric1, program as metric2 FROM Toto WHERE $__timeFilter(time)  ORDER BY 1`

[image: Grafana visualization option]